# Puppeteer - ExpressJS infinite loop a function

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I have a problem with my Express JS app : When I'm trying to call a function, this function is endlessly called ... It opens a lot of chromium browser and cause performance issues ...

I just want to call this function one time.

I've found a solution to make it work (And called just one time), but in this situation I can't pass any parameters ...

```
const farm = (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com/?s=" + term);
    await page.waitForSelector("div");
    const postLinks = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let postLinks = [];
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.article');
        for (element of elements) {
            postLinks.push({
                title: element.querySelector('div.meta-info > h3 > a')?.textContent,
                url: element.querySelector('div.meta-info > h3 > a')?.href
            })
        }
        return postLinks;
    });
    console.log(postLinks);
    await browser.close();
})();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var term = "Drake";
    res.send(farm);
});
```

With the code below, I can pass parameters but I can't return the result in "res.send", and the function is called endlessly :

```
const farm = async (term) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com/?s=" + term);
    await page.waitForSelector("div");
    const postLinks = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let postLinks = [];
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.article');
        for (element of elements) {
            postLinks.push({
                title: element.querySelector('div.meta-info > h3 > a')?.textContent,
                url: element.querySelector('div.meta-info > h3 > a')?.href
            })
        }
        return postLinks;
    });
    console.log(postLinks);
    await browser.close();
  }

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var term = "Drake";
    var results = farm(term);
    res.send(results);
});
```

Did I miss something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It's not an infinite loop, but unresolved promise. The `farm` returns a promise, which you're not waiting for, but instead send the pending promise before it resolves, i.e. before the puppeteer is done.

You need to wait for `farm`'s promise to resolve, make middleware function `async` and add `await` to the `farm` call:

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    var term = "Drake";
    // farm returns a promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve, i.e. block execution
    // otherwise it just sends pending promise, because node.js runs in non-blocking fashion
    var results = await farm(term);
    res.send(results);
});
```